# I am studying the TS tuples, what's wrong with this code?

Tags: typescript, tuples

The typescript tuple not worked as I wanted.

`tsc` version `3.6.4`

1、When I initialize a tuple like the following:

```js
let x: [string, number];
x[0] = 'John';
```

and got the following javascript through `tsc`:

```js
var x;
x[0] = 'John';
```

now run with `node`, I got this error:

```
/home/peng/ts-learnings/dist/tuple.js:2
x[0] = 'John';
     ^

TypeError: Cannot set property '0' of undefined
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/peng/ts-learnings/dist/tuple.js:2:6)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:956:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:973:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:812:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:724:14)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1025:10)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:11
```

and this is my `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
    "include": [
        "src/*.ts"
    ],
    "compilerOptions": {
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "target": "es2016",
        "outDir": "dist/",
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "types": [
            "reflect-metadata"
        ]
    }
}
```

Please tell me what's wrong.

2、And this code snippet also makes me confusing.

```js
type Person = [string, number];
let tom: Person = ['Tom', 35];
tom[0] = 'John';
tom[1] = 25;
tom.pop();
// ['John']
tom.push('test');
// ['John', 'test']
```

As some TS tutorials said, the statement `tom.push('test')` can not pass the compiler check, because `tom[1]` is the type of `number`!

Comment: Please specify your question

Comment: Check typescript [tuple](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#tuple) documentation for sample

Comment: @Anna I am sorry, I've read the documentation several times already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A good way to think about a tuple, is not really think about it as an array (even though it is in javascript).

If your tuple is specified as `[string, number]` it means that it always must have a 1 string and 1 number, in that order. No more, no less.

If you do a `.pop()` on that tuple, you reduce the number of items to 1, which means it's no longer the `[string, number]` type. Typescript prevents you from doing that, because one of typescript's goals is to ensure that if you define a variable as a certain type, it should always be that type.

So to answer why you can't run `.pop()` it really means 'you can't because you told typescript your variable is always the type `[string, number]`. If you want the ability to remove the last number, you need to use a different type.

So this ends up a bit of an XY problem. *why* are you trying to do this?

As for this snippet:

```
let x: [string, number];
x[0] = 'John';
```

The reason it doesn't work is because `x` is not initialized as an array. It should be corrected to something like:

```
let x: [string, number];
x = ['John', 25]
```